# Неинициализированная переменная P на C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Я писал код к следующем задаче:
В партии, состоящей из K изделий, имеются L дефектных.  Выбираются для контроля из партии R изделий. Найти  вероятность того, что партия будет забракована. Партия бракуется, если среди контрольных окажется более S дефектных изделий. Должно быть при вводе  `L< k` и  `r <k`.Если `L<S` или  `R<=S`,  то партия не бракуется.
Искомая вероятность:           [image: введите сюда описание изображения]      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int i;
float fact(int a)
{
    if (a < 0)
        return 0;
    if (a == 0 || a == 1)
        return 1;
    long f = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= a; i++)
        f *= i;
    return f;
}
float C(float x, float y)
{
    float pi;
    pi = fact(x) / (fact(x - y) * fact(y));
    return pi;
}
int main()
{
    int R, L, K, S;
    float P{};
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    system("color f0");
    //cout << "Введите переменные K,L,R так, чтобы они соответствовали следующим условиям: L < K && R < K\n";
    cout << "Введите количество изделий в партии: \n";
    cin >> K;
    cout << "Введите количество дефектных изделий в партии: \n";
    cin >> L;
    cout << "Введите количество изделий, взятых для контроля: \n";
    cin >> R;
    cout << "Введите количество дефектных изделий, найденных в контрольной партии: \n";
    cin >> S;
    
    if (L < K && R < K)
    {
        for (i=S + 1; R<i; i++)
        P += C(i,L) * C(R-i,K-L) / C(R,K);
        if (L < S || R <= S)
        {
            cout << "\nПартия не бракуется\n";
        }
    cout << "Вероятность забраковки партии = " << P*100 << "% \n";
    }
    else
    {cout << "Неверный ввод данных " << '\n';}
    return 0;
}
```

Код запускается, но выдаёт странное значение: -1.07374e+10%, однако перед тем, как выдать это значение, выдаёт следующую ошибку: Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'P' is being used without being initialized.
Если ввести в начале `P=0`, то будет выдаваться постоянно значение 0.
Помогите пожалуйста исправить это предупреждение, которое мешает правильной работе программы.

Comment: `float P{}, R{}, L{}, K{}, S{};` заменить, все. помимо этого, у вас путанница типов... Смотрите что вы там делаете.

Comment: @Kotomi, я не совсем понимаю, о какой путанице типов вы говорите. Вроде бы всё в порядке. У меня подозрения, что я не правильно записал сигму через цикл '''for''', но у меня очень маленький опыт программирования на C++, поэтому мне сложно какие-то выводы делать...

Comment: вы пишите в float целое, его дробная часть отпадает, и при значениях ниже чем 1.0 вы получите 0.

Comment: @Kotomi, я исправил. Только теперь вероятность (P) равна 0% постоянно.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была исправлена, поменяв в строке объявления функции C, поменять местами `float x` и `float y`, что выглядело так: `float C(float y, float x)`. Это сделано для того, что бы не получался отрицательный ответ, т.к. до этого выдавало, либо 0, либо `-nan(ind)`.
Далее я заметил, что в строке  `for (i=S + 1; R<i; i++)`, `R<i`, а такого не может быть ведь допустим, если R=4(количество изделий в контрольной), то `i = S + 1` будет в любом случае меньше, либо равно R, т.к. S - количество найденных дефектных изделий, найденных в контрольной партии. Поэтому я исправил это условие на `i<=R`, после чего программа стала работать.
Спасибо @Kotomi за помощь.